# Drupal7: Change node permission programmatically

Tags: drupal-7

I'm creating a custom Drupal 7 module and within my module I'm creating a node programmatically. In summary, it's something like this:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'donation';
node_object_prepare($node);
$node->title = 'Donation made on ' . date('r');
node_save($node);
```

How can I modify/set the permission for this dynamically created node so it's only accessible to admins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module and it solved my problem.